# client_email or client_id: which field to use to grant cluster-admin-rights before creating RBAC roles

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, rbac

I am deploying GKE components using [GKE API](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/).
Since it is an automated process, I am passing service-account.json to my program. This file is used for authenticating with GKE.

I want to deploy an RBAC role using the above setup.
According to [GKE-RBAC-Docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control), USER_ACCOUNT needs to be granted cluster-admin-binding before being able to make RBAC roles.

The service-account.json file has a field for `client_email` and another field for `client_id`.

On some clusters, I need to grant `client_email` as the User in cluster-admin-binding whereas on some `client_id`.

Can you tell me what I need to configure in my cluster so that only `client_id` is needed for creating RBAC roles?

Comment: just to clarify, the service-account.json is the key? or is it a file you wrote?

Comment: I suspect it is. You should be using the "client_email" field value with RBAC, not the ID